# How do I get a String Array of parameter names in a "ParameterMap" (in Java)

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I hava a ParameterMap set that has completely different parameters in different scenarios

What i need is a String Array of "keys" in the ParameterMap

The closest i have got is using reportParams.toString();

Here is what i used to get the folowing output

```
//The Code
ParameterMap reportParams = context.getRequestParameters();
System.out.println(reportParams.toString());
```

// The Output

map['username' -> 'user', 'decorate' -> 'no', 'decorator' -> 'empty', 'ajax' -> 'true', '_eventId' -> 'refreshReport', 'VEFactorSelection'-> '1', 'campusAndFaculty' -> array['111', '113', '115', '118', '112', '114', '116', '117', '21907', '21908', '99040', '99010', '99100', '99230', '99240'], '_flowExecutionKey' -> 'e4s1', 'reportLanguage' -> '3', 'date' -> '2013/06/20', 'nameType2' -> '1', 'confirm' -> 'true']

So what i want as end result is

username,
decorate,
decorator,
ajax,
_ecentId,
VEFactorSelection,
campusAndFaculty,
_flowExecutionKey,
reportLanguage,
date,
nameType2,
confirm

as Strings in a Array

===============================
So code now looks like:

```
ParameterMap reportParams = context.getRequestParameters();

final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

for (final Object o: reportParams.asMap().keySet())
names.add((String) o);

final String[] array = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);

System.out.println(array[0]);
```

End result:

===================================
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'org.hibernate.mapping.Map' for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [org.hibernate.mapping.Map] for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

===============================
Some extra's

Here is the API for "ParameterMap"
http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/webflow/core/collection/ParameterMap.html

Comment: "I can't use .keySet()" <-- yes you can

Comment: Oops sorry lol new to this hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ParameterMap` implements `MapAdaptable`, which has `.asMap()` to return a `Map`. I don't know whether your version uses generics; if it does, it's easy:

```
final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(map.asMap().keySet());
```

If it does not:

```
final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

for (final Object o: map.asMap().keySet())
    names.add((String) o);
```

After that, if you *really* want a `String[]` instead of a `List<String>`, use:

```
final String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Got a Error

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.webflow.core.c
ollection.LocalParameterMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Not sure what map to import

Comment: oops Wrong Form , Thx Man your Code Works :D !!

Comment: I get this error:__

org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'org.hibernate.mapping.Map' for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [org.hibernate.mapping.Map] for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: Uh, this is a Spring specific error... I guess you should ask another question about this one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly a `Map`, just do `map.keySet().toArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String names[] = reportParams.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```